# Writing an XYRectangle Class in Java

Tags: java, class, methods, constructor, field

I have the following class to write:
*Write a class named XYRectangle_LastName, where LastName is replaced with your last name.. The XYRectangle_LastName class should have the following fields:*

An XYPoint named TopLeft. This stores the location of the topleft corner of a Rectangle.

A double named Length.  This stores the length of the rectangle.

A double named Width.  This stores the width of the rectangle.

*The XYRectangle class should have the following methods:*

A no-argument constructor that randomly determines the top left corner of the rectangle.  The values for x and y should be between -10 and 10.  Also, it chooses a random width and length for the rectangle with values between 5 and 10.

A 3 argument constructor that takes an XYPoint for the top left corner, a length, and a width.

A get method for length, width, topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, and bottomRight

A set method for length, width, and topLeft

A boolean method named isInside that takes an XYPoint and determines if it is inside this rectangle.

A method named reflectX that returns a rectangle that has been reflected over the x-axis.

A method named reflectY that returns a rectangle that has been reflected over the y-axis.

This is the code I have so far:

```
public class XYRectangle {

    private XYPoint topLeft;
    private double length;
    private double width;

    public XYRectangle() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int x = (rnd.nextInt(21) - 10);
        int y = (rnd.nextInt(21) -10);

        XYPoint topLeft = new XYPoint(x, y);

        int width = (rnd.nextInt(5) + 5);
        int height = (rnd.nextInt(5) + 5);
    }

    public XYRectangle(XYPoint topLeft, double length, double width) {
        this.topLeft = topLeft;
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    public double getLength() { return this.length; }

    public void setLength(double length) { this.length = length; }

    public double getWidth() { return this.width; }

    public void setWidth(double width) { this.width = width; }

    public XYPoint getTopLeft() { return this.topLeft; }

    public void setTopLeft(XYPoint topLeft) { this.topLeft = topLeft; }
```

I'm having trouble with the topRight, bottomLeft, and bottomRight get methods and the reflect methods. I'm not even sure if the code I've written so far is write. Could anyone help and tell me how to proceed and if I've been doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, this sounds crazy I know, but ... how about you try compiling your code and stepping through it to see if it works?

Comment: Kind of stupid of me not to try the obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have the information about topRight, bottomLeft, and bottomRight, but having the topLeft corner and the width, length, it totally defines the other points:

```
topRight = new XYPoint(topLeft.getX() + length, topLeft.getY());
bottomRight = new XYPoint(topLeft.getX() + length, topLeft.getY() + width);
bottomLeft = new XYPoint(topLeft.getX(), topLeft.getY() + width);
```

You can decide to store this information when you construct your object or to calculate it each time the get method is called.

About the empty constructor, you are calling it "corner" when it should be called:

```
public XYRectangle(){
    //code here
}
```

Usually when we override constructors we call the base constructor like this:

```
public XYRectangle(){
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int x = (rnd.nextInt(21) - 10);
    int y = (rnd.nextInt(21) -10);

    XYPoint topLeft = new XYPoint(x, y);

    int width = (rnd.nextInt(5) + 5);
    int height = (rnd.nextInt(5) + 5);
    this(topLeft, width, height)
}
```

I hope you can figure out the reflection methods yourself. ;)

Comment: Thank you so much! It definitely makes it a lot easier.